# Setting folder level permissions within a team project in TFS (Team Foundation Server)

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to set different folder permissions within the same team project in Team foundation server 2010? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to see this [question/response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670490/set-up-user-permissions-for-team-foundation-server-2010)

You can also use the TFS Admin tool: http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com.

It is an easy tool to set the permissions for TFS, SharePoint and SSRS.