# Team Foundation Server 2010 DashBoard

Tags: c#, tfs

I have to access a TFS 2010 server and check some charts. How can I do that?
At this time, I am in the group Developers and have some collection access.

What kind of securty access do I need in order to see some charts?
Where will be the reports/charts menu?

Some articles mention SharePoint with TFS but Do I really need Share Point to see a simple BurnDown chart?

PS.: this is our first attempt to use TFS and learn the correct use of this tool for project management.

Answer (score 1):

First TFS can be installed without SharePoint and without Reporting service, and to view reports you just need Reporting service, because you may see reports using MS Excel, and to view reports on web you will need SharePoint

You can see my answer here for more information

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617900/verify-tfs-installation/9654052#9654052](http://First%20TFS%20can%20installed%20without%20SharePoint%20and%20without%20Reporting%20service,%20and%20to%20view%20reports%20you%20just%20need%20Reporting%20service,%20because%20you%20may%20watch%20reports%20using%20MS%20Excel,%20and%20to%20view%20reports%20on%20web%20you%20will%20need%20SharePoint)

Answer (score 0):

A Sharepoint portal and SQL Reporting Services should have been installed along with TFS.  I don't think you *can* install TFS without those.  You'll have to ask whoever performed the installation if they configured everything correctly.

In your Team Explorer you will have Work Items, Documents, Reports, Builds and Source Control items listed under the project name.

The reports are where any charts will be.  You might want to review how [security works for TFS](http://anlai.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-small-groups/).  You might also look at [Set up user permissions for Team Foundation Server 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670490/set-up-user-permissions-for-team-foundation-server-2010)

Comment: The person who installed TFS on the server is not on the company anymore. So now, I have to learn how to use it and use it well. :D

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2010, click on the the Team Explorer tab. Right Click on the project>Team Project Settings>Security. From there you can give either a group access or an individual. You also need to grant access to the Sharepoint dashboard and grant them access to the site. This is done at the site. Site Actions>Site Settings