# Verify TFS installation

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint, reporting-services, tfs

I have a server that was configured by someone that is not on the company anymore and I need to check the TFS installation and enable that "dasboard" with reports, charts etc.

The only stuff working are: Source Control, issue tracking, web access.

As far as I could check, Reporting Services seems to be disabled (or not installed) and I don't know how to check SharePoint installation.

How can I verify and fix the TFS installation in order to make the reports work?

If Reporting Services are not installed or disabled, where can I install or enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Team Foundation Server 2010 Best Practices Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248630.aspx) included in the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).

Comment: After you check the results by TFS Power Tools' Best Practices Analyzer, you can start up services using the TFS Management Console. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd273718.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you just open the TFS Admin Console, you can check for everything configured

- SharePoint
- Reports
- Others
  [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After that, start check this configuration per collection

[image]

If the SharePoint or Reporting not installed? You will need to install and configure them
For how to do this, there is a guide with videos on how to do enterprise installation, you can see the video of the SharePoint and Reporting only if you want, it will told you what exactly you will need to do?

http://tfs10enterprise.codeplex.com/releases/view/78529